# Why does my set comprehension throw a TypeError?

Tags: python, set, set-comprehension

I tried to change my original code with this set comprehension

```
next_states = {next_states | self.transition_function[(state, 
    input_value)] for state in e_closure_states}
```

But this code throws

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Original code (working as expected). Also, it should be mentioned that `self.transition_function[(state, input_value)]` is set and that's why I am using union. Thanks in advance

```
for state in e_closure_states:
    next_states = next_states | self.transition_function[(state, input_value)]
```

Comment: Remove the `next_states | `

Comment: @StephenRauch I get the same error.

Comment: Can you give some concrete example, what is next_states? Is that a set? A value?

Comment: @BillChen i’m not OP, but `next_state` is a set.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'` occurs because you're trying to add a set as an element of another set. As the error message implies, sets can only contain hashable elements, and sets themselves are unhashable.

I am not entirely sure that I understand what you’re trying to do, but tell me if this code produces the same thing as the `for` loop which you know is correct:

```py
next_states = set.union(next_states, *(self.transition_function[(state, input_value)] for state in e_closure_states))
```

`self.transition_function[(state, input_value)]` is copied from your code. That’s inside of a [`generator`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), as indicated by the parentheses. The asterisk (`*`) unpacks the generator into the `set.union()` call. You can read more about that [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/).

Comment: Yes, but however I can do it without set comprehension. Just was curious why isn't working and if I had a mistake somewhere on my code.

Comment: @M.Mar Was my explanation of the error clear enough? Do you have any questions?

Comment: @BillChen What do you mean? OP was getting an error message in his code, and I explained why. The post doesn’t actually mention what he is trying to do, so finding a solution is a bit tough. I have an idea of what he might be doing though, so I guess i’ll go off of that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I agree with you, I mean what is the solution here is depending on what the question is asking. I accidentally click the enter. :-)

Comment: @M.Mar I wrote a solution. If you are still having trouble understanding why you got the error, I can explain it fully. I just didn’t do it yet because i’m typing on a phone, which is difficult.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yea that actually worked. What is the * (self.transition_function[(state, input_value)]? Also, thank you!

Comment: @M.Mar I will update my answer to include an explanation of the code and some links, that way it’s more accessible.